# How can I add a row in a table created by a query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I a beginner with SQL. I first wrote a query which created a table. With this table I would like to add some rows. I thought that using "insert into" statement was the right idea, but it did not work.

```sql
insert into (
    select Element = [Key]
          ,New = max(case when time_index=1 then value end)
          ,'Current' = max(case when time_index>=2 then value end)
     From  (
            Select [time_index]
                  ,B.*
             From  (select * from ifrs17.output_bba where id in (602677,602777)) A
             Cross Apply (
                          Select [Key]
                                ,Value
                           From OpenJson( (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper ) )
                           Where [Key] not in ('time_index')
                         ) B
            ) A
     Group By [Key])
 values ('acc_test','test', 'test')
```

I receive this error message:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'values'.

How can I add rows to my table?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  `insert` inserts into an *existing* table.  To create a table, use `select into` or `create table as`, depending on the database you are using.

Comment: This is clearly SQL Server, based on the error. Please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using.

Comment: As for the problem, you want an `SELECT...INTO`: [SELECT - INTO Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UNION ALL to join the query and a row value constructs by elements:

```
insert into (
    select Element = [Key]
          ,New = max(case when time_index=1 then value end)
          ,'Current' = max(case when time_index>=2 then value end)
     From  (
            Select [time_index]
                  ,B.*
             From  (select * from ifrs17.output_bba where id in (602677,602777)) A
             Cross Apply (
                          Select [Key]
                                ,Value
                           From OpenJson( (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper ) )
                           Where [Key] not in ('time_index')
                         ) B
            ) A
     Group By [Key])
UNION
SELECT 'acc_test', 'test', 'test'
```

Comment: Thank you @SQLpro ! it works. Last question please. if now I would like to add several rows, how should I proceed?

Comment: Presumably wants `UNION ALL` otherwise you end up distincting the resultset unnecessarily. And what does `insert into (` do??

Comment: Use a serie a SELECT ... UNION ALL or the technic of Row Value Constructor https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15